# What is "amnesty" in an EEO statement?

Tags: discrimination

I came across this sentence in a job post:

> All applicants are considered without regard to race, color, religion, gender, sexual orientation, gender identity or expression, national origin, age, disability, genetic information, marital status, amnesty, or status as a covered veteran.

I understand all of the covered classes except for "amnesty". Is that related to immigration status?  Or maybe absolution of previous criminal convictions?

In case it's relevant, this was for a job in Florida, USA.

Comment: I won't make this an answer but I believe it refers to people who entered the US illegally but were granted an immigration amnesty. Technically they broke the law originally and I suppose this might still reflect in their record somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure  there's anything workplace-specific to bring up here. Wouldn't a dictionary definition suffice?

Comment: @Lilienthal So possibly better at [english.se] or [law.se]?

Comment: @DavidK Potentially, but I've found some references to this being about a specific law in which case it might be on-topic here. Turning this into an overview of all protected classes might make it a more useful question but that's for the OP to consider.

Comment: [Amnesty - an act of forgiveness for previous offenses](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amnesty). I had crafted an answer but was doing too much speculation on the legal side of things. I'm sure someone else out there understands things a bit better than me.

Comment: @Lilienthal workplace context: I'd like to make sure that I don't inadvertently commit an act [that my be taken as one] of discrimination (e.g., by asking an inappropriate question of a candidate).

Comment: @Dustybin80  -- I think you might be right; I just discovered that that DOJ/OCAHO has indicated that it is _**not**_ against US/Federal law to discriminate against those granted amnesty under DACA (see http://cis.org/north/justice-dept-daca-amnesty-recipients-not-protected-class )

Comment: @jhfrontz Looking at a specific "we don't discriminate clause" is meaningless then, that's just how one company decided to word it. The reference to amnesty doesn't appear in any official EEOC descriptions I've found, which I guess would make sense if you've found that it's not covered.

Answer (score 2):

Amnesty is explained as under:

> History of US Immigration and Amnesty
>   The storied history of United States amnesty began many years ago, as this is not a new topic. The immigration issue may have become more public, but it is an issue that has been around a long time. In fact, the immigrants have helped form America into the great melting pot that it is. Immigration is a very important part of US history. Before the United States became the way it is today, hundreds of thousands of immigrants settled on its land. The United States now have their own US Amnesty policy that can grant illegal immigrants a US pardon. This Amnesty policy is based on the fact that immigration is a large part of The US' history.
>
> It is important to understand the history of US immigration to
>   understand what prompted US amnesty policies. Without immigration,
>   there would be no need for amnesty policies. The United States has
>   always allowed immigrants into the country, and it has the most open
>   immigration policy in the world, according to the Center for
>   Immigration Studies. When America was young, it encouraged open
>   immigration to populate the country. States started passing
>   immigration laws after the Civil War.

Considering your:

> All applicants are considered without regard to race, color, religion, gender, sexual orientation, gender identity or expression, national origin, age, disability, genetic information, marital status, amnesty, or status as a covered veteran.

It states that the hiring process will be without any discrimination to the immigrants under the law.

[Immigration | Amnesty Source](https://www.usamnesty.org/)